# Load graph and then use it to build tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am very new to tensorflow,I am trying converting my .pb(proto buffer) file to lite version. But i am facing some issues.
import time,sys,warnings,glob,random,cv2,base64,json,csv,os

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import OrderedDict
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def, 
            input_map=None, 
            return_elements=None, 
            name="prefix", 
            op_dict=None, 
            producer_op_list=None
        )
    return graph
```

This function loads a graph for me and now i want to convert this graph to tflite for which i used the following script.

```
CD_graph = load_graph("CD_Check_k.pb")
CD_input = CD_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input_node:0')
CD_output = CD_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/output_node:0')
x_single = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 256 , 256, 3],
                              name="input_node")
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(CD_graph, input_tensors=[x_single ], output_tensors=[CD_output])
  with open('./mnist.tflite', "wb") as f:
      f.write(tflite_model)
```

Error msg:

```
'Graph' object has no attribute 'SerializeToString'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TocoConverter.from_frozen_graph()` API to simplify your code so you no longer need to read in the frozen graph. An example from the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md) is copied below.

### Exporting a GraphDef from file

The following example shows how to convert a TensorFlow GraphDef into a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer when the GraphDef is stored in a file. Both `.pb` and `.pbtxt` files are accepted.

The example uses [Mobilenet_1.0_224](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_frozen.tgz). The function only supports GraphDefs frozen via [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py).

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "/path/to/Downloads/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/frozen_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["input"]
output_arrays = ["MobilenetV1/Predictions/Softmax"]

converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```